# How to change only one property of a BuiltInView?

Tags: android, listview, xamarin

I'm a Xamarin Android beginner.  In an app that I'm writing, I created an Activity with a RadioGroup, and a button below it.

All was fine, until my radio buttons contained so much text that the radio group ran off the phone's screen, and the button was hidden.

So, I searched on the internet, and discovered that I could make the RadioGroup scrollable, by making it a ListView, and setting the ListView to be above the button.

Furthermore, I discovered that Xamarin Android offers the BuiltInView SimpleListItemSingleChoice which is a ready-made radio group as a ListView.

So, I implemented this, and all was fine, except that the text fields in each Item of the BuiltInView get cut short (i.e my radio button options to the user).

I want to apply the property

```
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

so that my long text labels for the radio buttons won't get cut short.

My question is, how do I apply this to each item of the BuiltInView?

I've tried to define my own custom view, but have run into problems trying to make it checkable, so I wondered if there is a simpler way to solve the problem by using the already provided BuiltInView.

In MyListAdapter GetView, I have

```
view = (context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItemSingleChoice, parent, false));
```

and in my Activity, I have

```
myListAdapter = new Adapters.MyListAdapter(this, myStrings, false);
myListView.Adapter = myListAdapter;
```

Comment: Please clear what you want.

Comment: "My question is, how do I apply this to each item of the BuiltInView?"

Comment: If you're using `wrap_content` with using Custom Adapter, you don't need to mention it for each then.

Comment: How do I use wrap_content with the Custom Adapter?  I don't know where to apply it to the BuiltInView.  I've only applied it to individual components like Buttons.

Comment: Do you have xml file of custom adapter?

Comment: I'm using a BuiltInView, so no, I don't have the definition.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74547/discussion-between-anshul-tyagi-and-s-list).

Comment: I gave a lot of information in the question, if you don't mind, I would rather not chat about it.  Thank you.

Comment: You are new in Android so you don't get what I'm asking and what I'm not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the BuiltInView does not offer an xml file (or I don't know where to access it in Xamarin), I added the following code to the custom Adapter's GetView method:

```
        var textLabel = view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1);

//I added these 2 lines to set the WrapContent property on each element of the BuiltInView
        AbsListView.LayoutParams layoutParams = new AbsListView.LayoutParams(AbsListView.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
                AbsListView.LayoutParams.WrapContent);
        textLabel.LayoutParameters = layoutParams;
```